# Principled BSDF + Substance Painter: change metallic colour

Tags: materials

So i've been fooling around with Substance Painter and Blender. My idea was to make this old fashioned or classic teacup and try to create the material in Substance. I do not have any experience with Substance, just fooling around.
Attached the cup and my question is: how can i change the metallic edge to a gold tone? I've searched all over the web but did not find any satisfying results.
In Substance i get the nice gold tone that i'm looking for, after export i end up with some kind of mask (it's grey-toned actually). So i would like to get the result from Substance into my Blender file for render.
I hope someone overhere can help me.
- Image cup in Blender with materials: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE7DB.jpg
- Substance material: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfOYt.jpg

Comment: Please share the mask that you are referring to. Also, try sharing the substance painter file. I'll take a look!

Comment: Here you go: https://we.tl/t-ANsa8Bi8cB

Comment: I have been digging around on the internet and found an export setting for Blender. This seems to work for me. I don't mind you taking a look at it, maybe you can come up with a nice solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me when I export textures with these settings.

[image]

The main difference between the textures I exported and those you provided is the base_color.

In the textures you shared 
[image]

When I exported
[image]

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what it should be! So it seems the settings for SP were incorrect? Thanks very much for your time, i will digg deeper into the settings for SP and hope to get the correct output with help from your screenshot of the export-setting for SP.